# ¿Cómo acumulo un producto ya existente en un mismo JTable?

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy realizando una práctica simulando un punto de venta. En el se agregan los productos desde un formulario a un **JTable**. El tema es que actualmente si hago **N veces clic** en el producto a agregar, se agregan esas N veces en **N numero de filas.**

Quiero que en caso de ya existir la misma *descripción del producto* (por ejemplo), solo se incremente el valor de la **Cantidad** en la misma fila del JTable, ya que mis campos en la tabla son Cantidad, Descripcion, Precio, Importe.

Desde este botón hago todo el procedimiento para agregar los productos desde mi tabla TblStock a la tabla tablaVenta en el FrmCaja

```
private void btnAgregarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    int selec = TblStock.getSelectedRow();
    try {
        String cantidad, descripcion, importe;
        String precio = null;
        double x, ivaS;
        
        DefaultTableModel modelo;

        modelo = (DefaultTableModel) TblStock.getModel();
        cantidad = txtCantidad.getText();
        descripcion = TblStock.getValueAt(selec, 1).toString();


        x = (Double.parseDouble(precio) * Integer.parseInt(cantidad));
        importe = String.valueOf(x);

        modelo = (DefaultTableModel) FrmCaja.tablaVenta.getModel();

        String registro[] = {cantidad, descripcion, precio, importe};
        modelo.addRow(registro);

         
        calcu = ((Double.parseDouble(precio)) * Integer.parseInt(txtCantidad.getText()));

        total = total + calcu;
        ivaS = total * .16;
        iva = ivaS;
        subtotal = total - ivaS;

        FrmCaja.txtTotal.setText("" + total);
        FrmCaja.txtIva.setText("$" + iva);
        FrmCaja.txtSubtotal.setText("$" + subtotal);

        FrmCaja.BtnPedido.setEnabled(true);
        FrmCaja.BtnPagar.setEnabled(true);
        FrmCaja.btnDescuento.setEnabled(true);

    } catch (HeadlessException | NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha seleccionado el tipo de mayoreo.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Buenas, Leonardo, bienvenido al sitio. Creo que lo que necesitas es crearte tu propia clase que extienda TableModel. De forma q en addRow añadas la lógica que indicas. Aquí se dan pautas sobre como hacerlo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316144/how-to-subclass-defaulttablemodel-and-change-its-datavector Ten en cuenta que aparte de la cantidad también estás introduciendo precio e importe nuevos. Supongo que esos dos querrás actualizarlos si el producto ya se encuentra ahí. Por último, yo identificaría los productos por una clave única, no por una descripción